# Change python indentation style vim

Tags: vim, python, configuration

At my current job they use the following formatting for multi-line arguments to a function

```
function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3
)
```

However my current vim setup will only allow the following style (which I also dislike:

```
function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3
    )
```

Can anyone suggest any changes that could allow this style of auto indent in vim.

This is everything in my vimrc to do with indentation:

```
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'edc/python-indent'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ setlocal tabstop=4 |
    \ setlocal softtabstop=4 |
    \ setlocal shiftwidth=4 |
    \ setlocal textwidth=79 |
    \ setlocal expandtab |
    \ setlocal autoindent |
    \ setlocal fileformat=unix |
    \ setlocal fileformat=unix |
    \ let b:indentLine_enabled = 0
```

I am open to using new plugins or just a change to the vimrc, but this is really annoying as I have to manually re-indent each time I want a multi-line function call

Comment: on my system, vim indentation definitions for python live here: `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/python.vim`. You can have a try at understanding what it does, maybe find the place or variable that defines the way the closing parenthesis is indented and either fix that or set the variable accordingly.